# How can I create a gradient shadowMap in threejs?

Tags: three.js

I want to show a shadowMap of a model that the center shadow is darker and the edge  is light(or thin),how can I set the properties?

Comment: Are you talking about the penumbra?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbra,_penumbra_and_antumbra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**soft shadow map** is the thing you are looking for.. just add

```
renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
```

before that remember to cast and receive shadows for the meshes/objects and  enable shadow map by adding

`renderer.shadowMap.enabled=true`

good luck...

Comment: Please, If you find this helpful dont forget to upvote and mark as useful. It will also be helpful for others